# Simple: Need help refactoring this awkward looking method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I need help refactoring this method. It is way too long.

```
  def report_total(feed_event, advisor)
    count = 0
    advisor.activity_feed_events.each do |lead|
      if lead == SignupFeedEvent
        count += 1
      else
        if lead.is_a?(feed_event) 
          if lead.event_date > (Time.now - 7.days)
            count += 1
          end
        end
      end
    end
    count
  end
```

Comment: Is this in a Rails app? Are the different types of `FeedEvent` in a single table (i.e. are you using STI)? A little context would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's a Rails app.

Comment: ActivityFeedEvent is the parent class and all the others (ex: SignupFeedEvent) inherit from this parent.

Comment: And are they all in the same table in your database (with a `type` column)?

Comment: @andy h Yup, thats correct!

Answer (score 3):

You could use scopes to do this at the database level, which would (potentially) be much faster than returning then iterating over all `ActivityFeedEvent`s.

```
# ActivityFeedEvent
scope :by_type, ->(type){ where(type: type.to_s) }
scope :recent, ->{ where("event_date > ?", Time.now - 7.days) }

# wherever report_total is
def report_total(feed_event_type, advisor)
  advisor.activity_feed_events.by_type(SignupFeedEvent).count +
    advisor.activity_feed_events.recent.by_type(feed_event_type).count
end
```

Note that you need a lambda for the `recent` scope despite it not taking args, because otherwise the Time.now will only be evaluated once (when the server starts).

Or, perhaps even more neatly, you could do it the other way round:

```
# ActivityFeedEvent
scope :for, ->(advisor){ where(advisor_id: advisor.id) }
scope :recent, ->{ where("event_date > ?", Time.now - 7.days) }

# wherever report_total is
def report_total(feed_event_type, advisor)
  SignupFeedEvent.for(advisor).count + feed_event_type.for(advisor).count
end
```

Depending on your models you may need a more descriptive name than `for` for this one, `belonging_to` or `for_advisor` are candidates.

Also note that some people prefer to write scopes as class methods instead of using lambdas

```
# ActivityFeedEvent
def self.for(advisor)
  where(advisor_id: advisor.id)
end

def self.recent
  where("event_date > ?", Time.now - 7.days)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Andy's solution with scopes is the one, so just to complement it, a refactor of your method using `sum` (although what you really need is `count`, see other answers):

```
def report_total(feed_event, advisor)
  advisor.activity_feed_events.sum do |lead|
    if lead == SignupFeedEvent ||
       (lead.is_a?(feed_event) && lead.event_date > (Time.now - 7.days))
      1
    else
      0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You could pull the boolean logic into a predicate method that takes `lead` as an argument.

Comment: yeah, something like `lead.reportable?`. But I wanted to focus on the refactoring of the same OP code.